# How can I recreate this spotty/polka dot/ confetti material procedurally

Tags: texturing, materials, node-editor, procedural

How can I go about recreating this with a procedural material. It's part of a comission and it needs to have seemingly randomly scattered spots of slightly different sizes and colours on a white surface.

Node set ups would be much appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 6):

It's quite simple node setup so I don't know if it needs explanation:

[image]

[image]

You could pass the upper Voronoi's Color through a color ramp to define your own colors, or you could connect it to *Hue* inside *Combine HSV* node to have all circles with very intense and bright colors.

Comment: This is great, thanks so much, excuse my node naivety but where can I find the scale, circle size and randomness nodes?

Comment: Those are all just Value nodes that you find in inputs when you add a node.  The OP simply changed the labels on the nodes to make them clearer.

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this. Just take the inverse of some 2D Voronoi dots (Clamped with a ColorRamp) with the randomness turned down, then multiply it by the colors from the Color Output, then invert it again:

[image: Dots]