# How can I recreate this polka dot multi color material procedurally

Tags: texturing, materials, node-editor, procedural, shader-nodes

How can I go about recreating this with [image: multi-color polka dot surface]procedural material?
Node setup would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't call it [Polka Dot](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/230479/60486), but here's my take at this effect:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. this was really helpfull