# Is it possibile to change and randomize the shape of voronoi texture generated dots so the they doesn`t look so even and perfect round?

Tags: node-editor, shaders, shader-nodes

[image]

In the image you can see a simple voronoi texture generated texture. The problem I have is that I don`t want that even look und the perfect circle shapes. Does somebody has an idea if it possible to randomly vary the shape of each dot a little bit? Thanks for every idea

Edit: Here is an example of what it looks like and what my  goal  is. I  marked the  outlines  red  so the inperfection  is  more  obvious.

[image]

Comment: In which way do you want it to vary? Can you provide an example?

Comment: I  edited  the  post and  added  an  image that shows  one  idea  of  I what  the  goal  is. I  hope  this helps. thanks

Comment: Very similar: [How can I recreate this polka dot multi color material procedurally](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/279912/60486)

Answer (score 2):

I tried around and solved my  problem. I mixed it up with a noise texture and controlled everything with colorramps. In the picture is the part I added behind the nodes from the question.

[image]

Here is what it does to the texture:

[image]

So  the problem is solved, now I will try to randomize them in there scale on the different axes, but if I will have a problem with that I will open a new post.

Answer (score 1):

That can be a setting of this kind:

[image]

Randomly shift the voronoi position between -0.5 / 0.5 with a given scale.

Use it to calculate the length to the shading point position.